# passing Objects from JSON and Convert to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I Have a USerBO like this

```
  [Serializable]
  public class UserBO
  {
    public string userId      { get; set; }
    public string userCode    { get; set; }
    public string userGroup   { get; set; }
  }
```

Have retrieved this Object from session. Now I need to pass this Object (USerBO) from javascript to a C# webmethod using JSON. Is it possible ?

Comment: Are you asking for a C# JSON parser?

Comment: _"Is it possible ?"_ Well, aren't we all intensely curious about this question? Every single day, many of us are writing code and asking ourselves: "Is it? Could it be that this would work?". "Perhaps" is the only answer. It depends. Have we written some code, or are we still staring at the dooming `void main`, seeking in utter dispair for inspiration? If the latter, I won't give you much hope. But if by any chance you wrote some code, and told us what you found out writing that code, and where you are stuck now, perhaps it would be possible for me to give an upvote. Or wasn't it about that?

Comment: Usually you retrieve an object from session on the server.  Are you looking to return that object in the web-method?  Or perhaps take it as an argument to a web-method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say webmethod, are you using an ASPX page method or ASMX ScriptService? If so, the answer is that [it's very easy to send that object from the browser to your method](http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/).

A page method like this one:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool SaveUserBO(UserBO User) {
  // Assuming you had a .Save() method on that class, for example.
  return User.Save();
}
```

Would automatically hydrate its `User` parameter if you passed it JSON like this:

```
{'User':{'userId':42,'userCode':1,'userGroup':2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)

Comment: Hi Rob,Thanks  Have tried using  JavaScriptSerializer jss = new              JavaScriptSerializer();                                          UserBO user = jss.Deserialize<UserBO>(userBO); ... there is a problem at deserialization....System.ArgumentException: Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}'....Do I need to serialize the object before posting to webservice?